# I Need to fix a issue in antd tree component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

what my issue is
Scenario 1: It is not opening sub-lists after searching or removing any list name from the search bar
Scenario 2: After searching any list name in the search bar that is already selected, then after searching that selected list it is showing that list but its checkbox is not selected.
so what do I need after searching list name in the search bar if that list has a sub-list for example if I **New Watchlists** then I want to show that sub-list also that present under this list after searching in the search bar but right it coming with empty list you can see image below..

```
const hasSearchTerm = (n, searchTerm) =>
  n.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
const filterData = (arr, searchTerm) =>
  arr?.filter(
    (n) =>
      hasSearchTerm(n.title, searchTerm) ||
      filterData(n.children, searchTerm)?.length > 0
  );

function filteredTreeData(data, searchString, checkedKeys, setExpandedTree) {
  let keysToExpand = [];
  const filteredData = searchString
    ? filterData(data, searchString).map((n) => {
        keysToExpand.push(n.key);
        return {
          ...n,
          children: filterData(n.children, searchString, checkedKeys)
        };
      })
    : data;
  setExpandedTree([...keysToExpand]);
  return filteredData;
}
const Demo = () => {
  const [expandedKeys, setExpandedKeys] = useState([]);
  const [checkedKeys, setCheckedKeys] = useState([]);
  const [selectedKeys, setSelectedKeys] = useState([]);
  const [autoExpandParent, setAutoExpandParent] = useState(true);
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");
  const [tree, setTree] = useState(treeData);

  const onExpand = (expandedKeysValue) => {
    console.log("onExpand", expandedKeysValue); // if not set autoExpandParent to false, if children expanded, parent can not collapse.
    // or, you can remove all expanded children keys.

    setExpandedKeys(expandedKeysValue);
    setAutoExpandParent(false);
  };

  const onCheck = React.useCallback(
    (checkedKeysValue, e) => {
      if (e.checked) {
        if (e.node?.children?.length) {
          setCheckedKeys(
            _.union(
              checkedKeys,
              _.cloneDeep([
                ...e.node.key,
                ...e.node.children.map((child) => child.key)
              ])
            )
          );
        } else {
          setCheckedKeys(_.union(checkedKeys, [e.node.key]));
        }
      } else {
        if (e.node?.children?.length) {
          setCheckedKeys(
            _.union(
              checkedKeys.filter((item) => {
                return (
                  item !== e.node.key &&
                  !e.node.children.filter((child) => child.key === item).length
                );
              })
            )
          );
        } else {
          setCheckedKeys(
            _.cloneDeep(checkedKeys.filter((item) => item !== e.node.key))
          );
        }
      }
    },
    [checkedKeys, setCheckedKeys]
  );

  const onSelect = (selectedKeysValue, info) => {
    console.log("onSelect", info);
    setSelectedKeys(selectedKeysValue);
  };
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const checked = [];

    treeData.forEach((data) => {
      data.children.forEach((item) => {
        if (item.checked) {
          checked.push(item.key);
        }
      });
    });
    setCheckedKeys(checked);
  }, []);
  function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (searchValue) {
      const filteredData = filteredTreeData(
        treeData,
        searchValue,
        checkedKeys,
        setExpandedKeys
      );
      setTree([...filteredData]);
    } else {
      setTree(treeData);
      // setExpandedKeys([]);
    }
  }, [searchValue, checkedKeys]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Search
        style={{ marginBottom: 8 }}
        placeholder="Search"
        onChange={(e) => {
          setSearchValue(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <Tree
        checkable
        onExpand={onExpand}
        expandedKeys={expandedKeys}
        autoExpandParent={autoExpandParent}
        onCheck={onCheck}
        checkedKeys={checkedKeys}
        onSelect={onSelect}
        selectedKeys={selectedKeys}
        treeData={tree}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

[CodeSandBox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/controlled-tree-antd-4-19-1-forked-hv2cdv?file=/index.js:1392-1406)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you run the `filterTreeData` function, you assign the children to only the tree that contains the search term. So, you're searching `n` levels deep for the term. Notice that it works like I'd expect it to if you only search one level deep. That is, if the node has children, you return the node as such rather than filtering down all the children that don't also contain the term. when you filter with the string `"new"` in your example, you'll notice that none of the children in the collection "New Watchlists" contain the term and they are therefore filtered out leaving you with an empty array. My naive solution is to just return the children as in my following example:

```js
function filteredTreeData(data, searchString, checkedKeys, setExpandedTree) {
  let keysToExpand = [];
  const filteredData = searchString
    ? filterData(data, searchString).map((n) => {
        keysToExpand.push(n.key);
        return {
          ...n,
          children: n.children
        };
      })
    : data;
  setExpandedTree([...keysToExpand]);
  return filteredData;
}
```

I call this solution naive, because I'm not exactly sure what your use case is. There might be more conditional logic you need to render in there for first searching `n` levels deep for the term and then and returning the whole node if the term is discovered anywhere inside the node or children.

Comment: my use case is for both levels like right now that I am doing searchString and also if that I search sub-list parent name then their child will also visible

Comment: Did you try this implementation? Because it wasn't filtering out the data you're concerned about when I put that into the code sandbox

Comment: yeah I tried this it working that shows the child list also  but it's set to filer only n.children but needs the old condition also can filter in deep like both way need to work if i ant only any one search name that will any child name need to filter

Comment: by using this way I am only able to filter that node with children if I want to search fatr then it always searches with node will all children